# Deserializing List of Objects with Mirah for Codename One

Tags: json, codenameone, mirah

I am trying to use mirah for JSON to POJO mapping in an codenameone application. It works finde when i want to map a Simple JSON like 

`{"id":"1","name":"foo","classification":"10"}`
With this class:

```
public class Brand {
    private String id; 
    private String name;
    private String classification;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getClassification() {
        return classification;
    }

    public void setClassification(String classification) {
        this.classification = classification;
    }    
}
```

Now I want to wrap it in a Message Object, where i have a list of brands:

```
import java.util.List;

public class Message { 
    public List<Brand> brands;

    public List<Brand> getBrands() {
        return brands;
    }

    public void setBrands(List<Brand> brands) {
        this.brands = brands;
    }        
}
```

I use this Mirah Script for mapping:

```
data_mapper Message:MessageMapper
data_mapper Brand:BrandMapper
```

like shannah described [here](https://github.com/shannah/cn1-mirah-json-macros/blob/master/docs/json.md).

My code where I call my Webservice:

```
    MessageMapper scheduleMapper = new MessageMapper();
    DataMapper.createContext(Arrays.asList(
            scheduleMapper,
            new BrandMapper()
        ), new DataMapper.Decorator() {

        public void decorate(DataMapper mapper) {
            mapper.setReadKeyConversions(Arrays.asList(DataMapper.CONVERSION_NONE));
        }
    });



    try {
    Message  message = scheduleMapper.readJSONFromURL("http://localhost/php-REST-DigitaleMusterplatte/api.php/brands", Message.class);
        System.out.println(message);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Log.e(ex);
    }
```

This is the json response:

`{"brands":[{"id":"1","name":"foo","classification":"10"},{"id":"2","name":"bar","classification":"20"}]}`

I get this exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to get key brands for class interface java.util.List because it was not a registered object type
at ca.weblite.codename1.mapper.DataMapper.get(DataMapper.java:507)
at com.mycompany.app.dmp.models.MessageMapper.readMap(/Volumes/Windows VMS/Documents/Shared/NetBeansProjects/mirah_macro_utils/MirahMacroUtils/src/ca/weblite/mirah/utils/DataMapperBuilder.mirah)
at ca.weblite.codename1.mapper.DataMapper.readMap(DataMapper.java:719)
at ca.weblite.codename1.mapper.DataMapper.readJSON(DataMapper.java:780)
at ca.weblite.codename1.mapper.DataMapper.readJSON(DataMapper.java:792)
at ca.weblite.codename1.mapper.DataMapper.readJSONFromConnection(DataMapper.java:767)
at ca.weblite.codename1.mapper.DataMapper.readJSONFromURL(DataMapper.java:754)
at com.mycompany.myapp.MyApplication.start(MyApplication.java:96)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.codename1.impl.javase.Executor$1$1.run(Executor.java:123)
at com.codename1.ui.Display.processSerialCalls(Display.java:1152)
at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:969)
at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
```

The demo application [OSCONScheduler](https://github.com/shannah/cn1-mirah-json-macros/tree/master/OSCONSchedule) works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug.  But try changing `brands` to be `private` instead of `public`.  It could be getting confused over whether to use your accessor/mutable or to use the public var.